# Exporting millions of rows from Power BI desktop into CSV

Tags: database, powerbi, large-data

Is there a way to export millions of rows from Power BI desktop into a CSV file? Limitations are:

- no copy & paste (PC memory runs out)
- cannot use Power query Python script (corporate computer, does not allow installation of matplotlib)
- cannot use DAX studio (corporate computer, installation of third party apps is forbidden)

I tried simple copy & paste, memory runs out. Also, it is very slow and prone-to-failure method. Typical suggestions on the internet are using DAX studio and Python script in Power query, these are ruled out for reasons described above. I tried copying one column at a time into an Excel sheet, but Excel can only handle 1,048,576 rows at time. I have some four million rows I need to have at least.

Comment: Power BI is not designed for mass export of data, it is meant to consume and present it. You'll have to find a away to export into chucks then combine it into a csv file in python for example

Comment: You're right. It is very challenging to work with limited tools, as PBI is not quite capable of such task easily. I guess I will have to either go down that chunk by chunk path or insist for SQL server access.

Comment: if you have a table visual, you can Export data using the 3 dots on the visual, have you tried that?

Comment: That's a good idea, but apparently there is a 30k row limit when exporting from visuals. I ended up copy & pasting it in 500k chunks. Didn't take that long in the end, as "only" seven such batches was needed.

Comment: You might want to let your `corporate company` know what you're doing. The fact that they don't give you the tools to export and interact with this data in this fashion likely means you shouldn't be doing this. If this is your solution to this problem (and you're asking this question about it)  whatever you are trying to do is something your company can easily do for you. Its likely this workaround you are coming up with is not worth it and will just make more work for everyone in the end. sincerely, the guy who usually has to clean up this kind of nonsense

Comment: I know right, it's a project work and it is a total mess. The IT department has their hands full with normal company stuff and now the project work spills into their hands too. And of course, I wouldn't be doing these half-assed solutions unless I was told to.

Answer (score 0):

1. Publish to PowerBI.com
2. From Excel, click **Data > Get Data > From Power Platform > From Power BI**.
3. Pick your Power BI dataset. Excel creates a connection to Power BI and opens a PivotTable.
4. Create any little pivot that shows data
   [image: happy little pivot]
5. Double click on a data point in the Pivot to create a drill-through table. The Drill-through table will have a specific query behind it that you will hijack. This is just the easiest way to get there.
6. Right click the drill-through table and select **Table > Edit Query...**
   [image: happy little drill-thru table]
7. Change the query to EVALUATE 'my_table_to_export' and click OK
   [image: happy little DAX]

That DAX will run and pull back the whole table, and remarkably fast. If it doesn't fit in a million rows, use DAX [FILTER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/filter-function-dax)s to limit the data into million row chunks. This page has some great examples: https://www.sqlshack.com/query-ssas-tabular-model-database-using-dax-functions/

such as

```
EVALUATE(FILTER('Geography', [State Province Name] = "North Carolina"))
```